# How to commit changes in WPF DataGrid to ObservableCollection Source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have DataGrid Conrol

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Faculties}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and View Model

```
private ObservableCollection<Faculty> faculties = new ObservableCollection<Faculty>();
public ObservableCollection<Faculty> Faculties
{
    get { return faculties; }
    set 
    { 
        faculties = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Faculties");
    }
}
```

Faculty class:

```
public class Faculty
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

How to save changes in DataGrid to my collection? Two-Way Binding does not help

Comment: Can you expand _save changes in DataGrid to my collection_? Do you mean `Title` edits?

Comment: **Unclear what you're asking.** - what is the current behavior and how is it different from the expected one? please edit your question and add... a question.

Comment: This blog post may be relevant; your changes are probably being committed on a per-row basis instead of a per-cell basis (i.e. nothing is committed until input focus leaves the current row).  http://codefluff.blogspot.com/2010/05/commiting-bound-cell-changes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately your `Faculty` class should implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) interface to make it work. (The `ObservableCollection` will only force updates if the collection itself changes - elements are added or removed - and **not** when properties of elements in the collection change.)

Comment: Looks like it doesn't works too, because I invoked PropertyChanged in Setter but event handler of CollectionChanged event didn't call

Comment: Well, the CollectionChanged event shouldn't fire if you change a property of an element inside the collection, as the collection did not change. Make sure you check the example on the msdn page for INotifyPropertyChanged and implement your Faculty class according to that. Also consider updating your question with the new code.